# Get the value from the form and insert that value in the table by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have created simple form and table.. So I need to add values from the form. I have created the code but it is not working.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        function clickFunction(){
            document.getElementByName('inputvalue').innerHTML = document.getElementByName('name');
            }
    </script>
    <form>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" value="Done" onclick="clickFunction()">
    </form>
    <table border="1">
        <tr><td>Data input: </td><td><label name="inputvalue" > null </label></td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things you have to fix first:

1. It should be `document.getElementsByName`, you are missing a 's'.
2. Since, the submit is in a form element. Once you click it, it will submit the form. So, you should stop it by using `return false` in the function.
3. To get the value from the input box, you should add 'value' after `document.getElementByName('name')`. it should be `document.getElementByName('name').value`.
4. I have added `e.preventDefault`. In-case, it tries to submit. In that case, there is a slight change in HTML.

   ...
   `<input type="submit" value="Done" onclick="clickFunction(event)">`
   ...

The corrected source code: https://jsfiddle.net/gy03xz4b/4/

HTML is fine, the js will change a bit:

```
 function clickFunction() {
   document.getElementsByName('inputvalue')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
   return false;
 }
```

Hope that helps!

Refers:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName
2. http://www.irt.org/script/155.htm (What does 'return false' do?)
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault (e.preventDefault)

Comment: why it shows 'null' again . after we add the value ?. I mean, when I insert the value as "1" and click " done " button, then it get the value into the table but it shows null text again.

Comment: you mean initially, or after adding the value? Are you checking the JSfiddle?

Another thing I noticed was that, you has set 'null' to the label. `<label name="inputvalue"> null </label>`. That is the reason, initially its null. Remove that, and it will not show null.

Comment: I means affter adding the value. And I have checked the JSfiddle. Thank you.  It is working now :)